# Is it possible to pass context into a component instantiated with ReactDOM.render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TL;DR Given the following example code:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent prop1={someVar} />, someDomNode);
```

Is it possible to manually pass React `context` into the instance of `MyComponent`?

I know this sounds like a weird question given React's nature, but the use case is that I'm mixing React with Semantic UI (SUI) and this specific case is lazy-loading the contents of a SUI tooltip (the contents of the tooltip is a React component using the same code pattern as above) when the tooltip first displays. So it's not a React component being implicitly created by another React component, which seems to break `context` chain.

I'm wondering if I can manually keep the `context` chain going rather than having components that need to look for certain data in `context` AND `props`.

React version: 0.14.8

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. Before react 0.14 there was method `React.withContext`, but it was removed.

However you can do it by creating HoC component with context, it would be something like:

```
import React from 'react';

function createContextProvider(context){
  class ContextProvider extends React.Component {
    getChildContext() {
      return context;
    }

    render() {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }

  ContextProvider.childContextTypes = {};
  Object.keys(context).forEach(key => {
    ContextProvider.childContextTypes[key] = React.PropTypes.any.isRequired; 
  });

  return ContextProvider;
}
```

And use it as following:

```
const ContextProvider = createContextProvider(context);

ReactDOM.render(
  <ContextProvider>
    <MyComponent prop1={someVar} />
  </ContextProvider>,
  someDomNode
);
```

Comment: I suspected it was impossible to manually continue the `context` chain. The React docs and what I could interpret of the source code looked like it was impossible that way, but I wanted to make sure. I had seen a solution similar to this elsewhere.

Comment: Hey can you expand on this solution a bit, I'm not quite sure how it works, and I've run into something similar where I'm trying to manage the rendering of elements based on events but some of these elements need the ReactReduxContext (or so i believe)

Comment: @steff_bdh it dynamically creates context a provider with the specific fields in it. however, this is already a legacy API, and redux is probably already using a new one. Can you create a new question with example code for issue you are trying to address?

Answer (score 2):

In React 15 and earlier you can use `ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer` instead of `ReactDOM.render`. The first argument is the component who's context you want to propagate (generally `this`)

In React 16 and later there's the "Portal" API: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html