# React Router Link doesn't work with LeafletJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-router, react-leaflet

Versions:

- react-router-dom 4.1.1
- react-router-redux 5.0.0-alpha.4
- react-leaflet 1.1.3
- leaflet 1.0.3

### Steps to reproduce

I create a leaflet map. In which I add some markers. These markers have popups.
In each of these popup I want to have a `<Link>`

Also if it helps this is my Routing config:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <AppContainer />
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <div>
          <MenuContainer />
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/:area/:sport/list' component={ListContainer} />
            <Route path='/:area/:sport/map' component={MapContainer} />
            <Route path='/:area/:sport/rasp' component={RaspContainer} />
            <Route path='/:shortcode/details' component={StationDetailsContainer} />
            <Redirect exact from='/' to='/wellington/paragliding/list' />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </div>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

### Expected Behavior

I can see my link and click on it when popup opens.

### Actual Behavior

[image: Actual behaviour]
Impossible to see the link. It's not generated.

### Extra details

Inside my `<MapMode>` I use `<Map>` from leaflet.
If I set a `<Link>` just above the `<Map>` tag it works.
As soon as I want to have a link inside my `<Map>`, somehow it breaks.
This is the React structure of my page, `<Popup>` tag just contains `null` as Javascript is breaking:
[image: React structure]

It's quite a complex problem so feel free to ask me questions.
Thanks.

Comment: Is `history` that is passed to ConnectedRouter has value ? Looks like it is undefined.

Comment: @Panther no it has a value if you look at the React structure. Also if I set a link just above the <Map> it's working fine.
React-router contributor suggests it could be linked to LeafletJS creating a portal? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4979#event-1045005333
Don't know how I could avoid that though :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about this answer. But anyway I'm going to try because I think at least it might shed some light to anyone who will try to solve this problem in future.

I got the first hint from [this issue](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/310) in `react-leaflet` GitHub repo. According to that and your error, it seems the problem is Popup can't access the `router` from the `context` because `context` isn't passed into the Popup with the way they render it. So we should be able to fix the problem if we can explicitly pass the context to Popup.

Then I found a way to explicitly pass the context into a component in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212174/is-it-possible-to-pass-context-into-a-component-instantiated-with-reactdom-rende) StackOverflow answer. With that, I think you should be able to use a HoC(Higher order Component) as follows to solve your problem.

This is the HoC that inject context to a component:

```
function withContext(WrappedComponent, context){

  class ContextProvider extends React.Component {
    getChildContext() {
      return context;
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  ContextProvider.childContextTypes = {};
  Object.keys(context).forEach(key => {
    ContextProvider.childContextTypes[key] = React.PropTypes.any.isRequired; 
  });

  return ContextProvider;
}
```

Let's say you are using Popup inside a component called MapMaker. Then you can inject the context with `router` into Popup using the HoC like this.

```
class MapMaker extends React.Component {

  //......

  // This make sure you have router in you this.context
  // Also you can add any other context that you need to pass into Popup
  static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render(){

    const PopupWithContext = withContext(Popup, this.context);

    return (
      //..... your JSX before Popup
      <PopupWithContext/> // with your props
      //..... your JSX after Popup
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Perfect! I just created a `LinkWithContext` instead of `PopupWithContext` and it worked for me!

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 11):

I tried the solution suggested by Tharaka but it didn't work for me. It looks like react-leaflet's Popup is using it's own context, thus blocking context that is passed from higher levels. However, inspired by this solution I came up with another one, really simple & based on the composition principal.

I created RouterForwarder component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class RouterForwarder extends Component {
  getChildContext() {
    return this.props.context
  }

  render() {
    return <span>{this.props.children}</span>
  }
}

RouterForwarder.childContextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

RouterForwarder.propTypes = {
  context: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default RouterForwarder
```

and then used it in my component (the one that renders Map, Marker, Popup & Link) in the following way:

```
import RouterForwarder from './RouterForwarder'

class MyComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
    ...
      <Popup>
        <RouterForwarder context={this.context}>
          <Link to={'my destination'}>Go to My Destination</Link>
        </RouterForwarder>
      </Popup>
    ...)
  }
}

MyComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object,
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get the selected answer working, but this worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: With due credit to Tharaka, I think this improved and simpler solution is better in most cases.

Answer (score -1):

My solution (it's a workaround but works great and I see no downsides):

I solved by using (in react router **v3** with **redux**)

```
<a onClick={() => goTo(params)} />
```

whereas `goTo` is defined in

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
  goTo(id) {
    return push(`/<url>/${id}`); // push from 'react-router-redux'
  },
}, dispatch);
```