# Is it possible to pass context to dumb child component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Note: This isn't related to my problem but I already viewed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212174/is-it-possible-to-pass-context-into-a-component-instantiated-with-reactdom-rende).

Say I have my app component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    // stuff & code
    <Header />
    // code & stuff
}

App.childContextTypes {
    router: Proptypes.object.isRequired;
}
```

And then I have a Header component which **I defined as a constant**:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

getPath() {
    const router = { this.context };
    return router.location.pathname; 
}

const Header = (props) => { 
    // header stuff
    <div>{getPath()}</div>
}

Header.contextTypes {
    router: Proptypes.object.isRequired;
}
```

all the above is dummy code, but it's what I have in a nutshell. So far when I try to access the router object in the header, the `router` object is `undefined`.  Is it possible to pass through props in such a way to a component that is a `const` and not defined explicitly as a React class?

In my react project I am using react-router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have context passed to stateless components. [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#referencing-context-in-stateless-functional-components)

You will get context in the second argument.

```
const Header = (props, context) => 
{
      console.log(context);
      return (<div></div>);
} 
Header.contextTypes = { 
    router: Proptypes.object.isRequired; 
}
```