# How can I replace Markdown-rendered HTML tags with React components?

Tags: reactjs, markdown

At the moment, I'm converting the Markdown to HTML code using `marked`, then I replace some parts of it with React elements. This results in an *array of HTML strings and React elements*, which can be rendered indeed:

```
const prepareGuide = markdown => replaceToArray(
  marked(markdown),
  /<a href="SOME_SPECIAL_HREF".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/,
  (match, label, slug) => <a href={`/${slug}`}>{label}</a>
)

const Guide = ({ guide }) =>
  prepareGuide(guide.fields.text).map(
    n => typeof n === 'object'
      ? n
      : <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: n }} />
  )
```

The problem with this, let's just call it workaround, is that every piece of HTML needs a wrapper element, like `span` (and uses `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`).

What I basically need is the ability to replace the rendered HTML elements with React components to add React functionality like Router links and other, custom elements.

Any other approaches?

Edit: The [replaceToArray](https://github.com/oztune/string-replace-to-array) function I used is like `String.prototype.replace`, but returns an array (so any type can be returned)

Edit: Another approach I had was to render the HTML directly to the DOM (using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`), and using the container element's `ref` to query all elements I want to replace. But, next problem: To render React components inside the HTML ref I have, I'd need another React root, which is possible, but unpractical, because I'd lose all the contexts (like Router), so I can't even properly use Router Links that way.

Comment: maybe have a look at https://github.com/rexxars/commonmark-react-renderer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this as follows:

I kept using `marked` and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to directly set the HTML. Now, as described in the second approach, I used the `ref` to query the elements I want to replace. Now to be able to render React elements to the HTML, I just used the `ReactDOM.render` function.

The biggest problem with this was that components didn't have access to the app's context, since I now had multiple React roots. To solve this, I figured out that we can copy the context from one component to another: [Is it possible to pass context into a component instantiated with ReactDOM.render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212174/is-it-possible-to-pass-context-into-a-component-instantiated-with-reactdom-rende)

So to be able to access the context in the component that renders the HTML, we need to set the component's `contextTypes` for the contexts we need to copy.

```js
class Article extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.any
  }

  static propTypes = {
    markdown: PropTypes.string
  }

  prepare(ref) {
    const Provider = createContextProvider(this.context)
    const links = Array.from(ref.querySelectorAll('a'))

    links.forEach((link) => {
      const span = document.createElement('span')
      const { pathname } = url.parse(link.href)
      const text = link.innerText

      link.parentNode.replaceChild(span, link)
      ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider>
          <Link to={pathname}>{text}</Link>
        </Provider>,
        span
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <article
        ref={this.prepare}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: marked(this.props.markdown) }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

The above code requires the snipped which I copied from the question linked above. The method I called `prepare` replaces specific HTML nodes with React roots.

```js
function createContextProvider(context) {
  class ContextProvider extends React.Component {
    getChildContext() {
      return context
    }

    render = () => this.props.children

    static propTypes = { children: PropTypes.node }
  }

  ContextProvider.childContextTypes = {}
  Object.keys(context).forEach(key => {
    ContextProvider.childContextTypes[key] = PropTypes.any.isRequired
  })

  return ContextProvider
}
```

So we basically have a function that creates a `Provider` component. That function needs to be able to dynamically adapt to the required context types, that's why the loop sets them to be required.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to have **links** work with React Router, you can render the markdown as usual with dangerouslySetInnerHTML then **intercept internal link clicks** to make them go through react-router.

Full example of loading .md externally, then catching links to process with react-router:

```
import React from "react"
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

import catchLinks from 'catch-links'
import marked from "marked"

import styles from './styles.scss'

class ContentPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            markdown: '',
            title: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            catchLinks(window, (href) => {
                this.props.history.push(href);
            });
        }

        const page = location.pathname.replace('/', '');

        fetch(`/assets/content/${page}.md`)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            this.setState({ markdown: marked(text, {}) })
        });

        const title = page_titles[page] || capitalize(page);

        if (title) {
            document.title = title;
            this.setState({title})
        }

    }

    render() {

        const {
            markdown,
            title
        } = this.state;

        return (
            <div class={styles.contentPage}>

                <div class={styles.pageTop}>
                    {title}
                </div>

                <div class={styles.page}>
                    <div class={styles.content} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: markdown}}></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(ContentPage);
```